# How to assign ROW_NUMBER() to a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293390/sql-to-output-line-number-in-results-of-a-query), I have another similar question. Is there a simple way to get this SQL statement to work?

```
update [Insurances] set [RowNo]=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [RowNo])
```

I have a `RowNo` column which I want to update whenever a record is deleted.

Comment: You really should do this in a view instead of in the actual table...

Comment: @JNK Could you be a little more specific? I'm pretty new to the SQL world

Comment: If all you want to know is what order the row is within a certain ordering logic, it shouldn't be a part of the actual row since it's metadata.  Create a `ROW_NUMBER()` field in a view and just use that.

Comment: @JNK Actually I change that `RowNo` column to modify each row's position in my resultset.

Comment: Then it is indeed a  terrible idea.  Just use a view instead.

Comment: do you keep the `RowNo` when you delete a record(Single Row I assume) ? a simple/quick thought instead using `RowNumber()` to resequence would `update Insurances SET RowNo = RowNo - 1 Where RowNo >= DeletedRowNo` works ?

Comment: @Turbot Unfortunately I expect multiple row deletions to occur sometimes.

Comment: Why do you need to store this. Ever. You can always generate the number at runtime and it is guaranteed to be up to date without having to constantly scan the entire table with a trigger every time a row is added, updated or deleted.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I need it because I need to let my users move the records up and down at their discretion.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand why you can't just change the RowNo value instead of recalculating it for the whole table.

Comment: @iManBiglari - you don't need to update the `RowNo` since it is internally assigned and not visible to user. so either i don't understand why you need to update the whole table with the row_number().

Comment: There are some legitimate needs for doing this operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Update with row\_number()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.RowNo = s.RowNo  
FROM  [Insurances] t1
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Somefield DESC) RowNo
     FROM Insurances
) s ON t1.Id = s.Id
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, until I move the line begins with `SET` to right after `UPDATE t1` at the top

Answer (score 2):

I would join the table to a subquery (not sure if you can do that in SQL Server) or create a view and join the table to that in the update:

```
CREATE VIEW InsurancesView AS
SELECT insuranceID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY RowNo ) AS newRowNo
  FROM Insurances;
```

(assuming you have a primary key named `insuranceID`)

```
UPDATE Insurances AS i
 INNER JOIN InsurancesView AS iv
    ON i.insuranceID = iv.insuranceID
   SET i.RowNo = iv.newRowNo;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name ) RowNo FROM lu_Domain
)
UPDATE dbo.lu_Domain
SET SortOrder = cte.RowNo
FROM dbo.lu_Domain d
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.id = d.Id
```