# Sort column values to match order of values in another table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

Let's say I have table like this:

```
Column1            Column2
C                     2
B                     1
A                     3
```

I need to exchange values in the second column to get this:

```
Column1            Column2
C                     3
B                     2
A                     1
```

The goal is only for numeric column to have values sorted to follow alphabetical order on another column. The actual table has multiple columns and column 1 is people's name, while column 2 two is rank for rendering column 1 values in UI.

What is the most optimal way to do this?
I am doing this from C# code, on SQL server and have to use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand because of transaction. But maybe it's not important if this can all be done from SQL.

Thank you!

Comment: `select col1,col2 from tablename order by col1,col2`

Comment: yes, but I need to update the table values

Comment: give correct example.there is no logic in your current example.Why C=3 when actually it is c=2.If there is two table involve then give example accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Update with row\_number()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number)

Comment: Kumar, as far as I know, C is the third letter in English alphabet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to update `Column2` with the row-number according to`Column1`?

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx) and a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT Column1, Column2, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1)
    FROM MyTable
)
UPDATE CTE SET Column2 = RN;
```

This updates the table `MyTable` and works because the CTE selects a single table. If it contains more than one table you have to `JOIN` the  `UPDATE`  with the `CTE`.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39e42/2/1)</kbd>

Comment: My question was not above row numbers, I have edited it to add more details. It about sort numeric column values to follow alphabetic ordering of another nvarchar column.
But I think in my case will be able to do something even with this.