# How to fill column basing on two other columns

Tags: t-sql

I have table `LessonHour` with empty `Number` column.

```
TABLE [dbo].[LessonHour]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [SchoolId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NULL
)
```

How can I fill up the table with `Number` for each `LessonHour` so it would be the number of lesson hour in order? 
The `LessonHours` cannot cross each other. Every school has defined its own lesson hour schema.

Example set of data
http://pastebin.com/efWCtUbv

What'd I do:

1. Order by SchoolId and StartTime
2. Use Cursor to insert into row next number, starting from 1 every time the `SchoolId` changes.

---

Edit:

Solution with cursor

```
select -- top 20
        LH.[Id],
        [StartTime],
        [EndTime],
        [SchoolId]
into #LH
from
    LessonHour as LH
    join RowStatus as RS on LH.RowStatusId = RS.Id
where 
    RS.IsActive = 1

select * from #LH order by SchoolId, StartTime

declare @id uniqueidentifier, @st time(7), @et time(7), @sid uniqueidentifier
declare @prev_sid uniqueidentifier = NEWID()
declare @i int = 1
declare cur scroll cursor for
select * from #LH order by SchoolId, StartTime
open cur;
fetch next from cur into @id, @st, @et, @sid
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    --print @prev_sid
    if @sid <> @prev_sid
    begin
        set @i = 1
    end

    update LessonHour set Number = @i where Id = @id

    print @i
    set @i = @i + 1

    set @prev_sid = @sid
    fetch next from cur into @id, @st, @et, @sid
end;
close cur;
deallocate cur;

drop table #LH
```

This is the result I was after http://pastebin.com/iZ8cnA6w

Comment: You've got a problem and you have an idea how to solve it. But what is your question? Did you implement and test your solution? Did you run into any problem or do you want to know if there are better ways to do it?

Comment: Very unclear, but lets try with `ROW_NUMBER()` **[demo....    ҉](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422677)**

Comment: @WernerHenze I'm looking for a better solution. I don't like using cursor, but I have no idea how to do it any other way.

Comment: @lad2025 I like that, going to give it a try.

Comment: Please let me know if it suits you. If yes I will post it as answer.

Comment: So you told us what you would do, but did you do it?

Comment: @dfundako check my update. It actualy works, but I'd like to see a solution without using a cursor. Just curious.

Comment: can you show the before and after of the results?

Comment: @KamranFarzami see my comment to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Merging the information from the StackOverflow questions [SQL Update with row_number()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number) and 
[How do I use ROW_NUMBER()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961007/how-do-i-use-row-number):

```
with cte as (
    select number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by schoolid order by starttime asc) as r from lessonhour
)
update cte
set number = r
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this work

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LessonHour]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [SchoolId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Number] AS DATEDIFF(hour,[StartTime],[EndTime])
)
```

So if I understand the question correctly you require a calculated column which takes in the values of [StartTime] and [EndTime] and returns the number of hours for that lesson as an int. The above table definition should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: No. I need to number lesson hours for every school.

Comment: After running `UPDATE [dbo].[LessonHour]
   SET [Number] = DATEDIFF(hour,[StartTime],[EndTime])` I get this http://pastebin.com/tKRFp4h3