# SQL Set Index (order value) to column

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Short story**

I have 'Rows' table for my `Requests`. Currently, when I add new row to request, there is no way to order them, so I added `Index` column. This would enable to add new rows and order them as I wish.

**What I want to do**

I want to write MSSQL script that **sets** default values for old rows to `Index` (0, 1, 2) by `InvoiceRequestId`. This should currently be set as they are (`Id` order).

**Current table**

```
Id    InvoiceRequestId  Index
2734  620               0
2735  620               0
2736  621               0
2737  622               0
2738  622               0
2739  622               0
...
```

**What I want to achieve**

```
Id    InvoiceRequestId  Index
2734  620               0
2735  620               1
2736  621               0
2737  622               0
2738  622               1
2739  622               2
...
```

**Edit**

I see, that some started to post answers for only those rows. This should be general solution, my bad, that I didn't clarify this before.

**Solution**

So thanks for the answers below and this topic [SQL Update with row_number()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number) , I found the following solution to work:

```
With IndexUpdate As
(
    SELECT [Index],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceRequestID ORDER BY ID) -1 as RN
    FROM [InvoiceRequestRows]
)
UPDATE IndexUpdate SET [Index]=RN
```

Comment: I have updated the answer for the update, you can check that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` function

```
select *,
      (row_number() over(partition by InvoiceRequestId order by Id)-1)  
from table
```

**EDIT :** Use `CTE` for subquery resultset in order to update index with newly created index

```
;with cte as
(
  select *,
       (row_number() over(partition by InvoiceRequestId order by Id)-1) newindex 
  from table
)
update t set t.[Index] = c.newindex 
from cte c
join table t on t.Id = c.Id
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how can I use this in update method, so my [Index] column would use those values?

Comment: Why would I want to use join? Statement, that I put into my original question as solution seems to work as well.

Comment: @Taurib .. yes no need for explicitly `join` but,  `join` would be guaranteed update your index with appropriate  `id's`

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to add a column if you want to get those results, you can use the ROW_NUMBER function e.g.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(Id INT, InvoiceRequestId INT);
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
(2734, 620),
(2735, 620),
(2736, 621),
(2737, 622),
(2738, 622),
(2739, 622);

SELECT Id,
       InvoiceRequestId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InvoiceRequestId ORDER BY Id) AS [Index]
FROM @table;
```

Will give you:

```
Id  InvoiceRequestId    Index
2734    620             1
2735    620             2
2736    621             1
2737    622             1
2738    622             2
2739    622             3
```

It starts the count at 1 rather than 0 but the results are the same. You can add a '-1' if you need it to be 0

If you still want to add the column then you can build a temp table using the same function and insert from there

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the `RANK` functions in SQL Server, to create a new column called `NewIndex` for example

Link [here](https://15to20minutes.com/2017/07/03/ranking-function-in-sql-server/)

```
SELECT ID, InvoiceRequestID, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceRequestID ORDER BY ID) -1 AS NewIndex
FROM SomeTable
```

To update the `Index` column you could use this (although I haven't tested this code...)

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET [Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvoiceRequestID ORDER BY ID) -1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your solution is just to select, but how could I update [Index] to set this value?

Comment: @Taurib You can use the same expression in your UPDATE statement, I will edit my answer

Comment: With your update script I get `Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`

Answer (score 2):

Following query should work. ROW_NUMBER -1 is being done as you are looking for index to be stared from 0.

```
    WITH Requests as (
    select * from (values 
        (2734 , 620 ,   0)
        ,(2735,  620 ,   0)
        ,(2736,  621 ,   0)
        ,(2737 , 622 ,   0)
        ,(2738,  622 ,   0)
        ,(2739,  622 ,   0)
      ) t (Id, InvoiceRequestId  , [Index])
    )

SELECT Id, InvoiceRequestId,(ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(PARTITION BY  InvoiceRequestId 
    ORDER BY Id, InvoiceRequestId ASC)-1) AS Index
 FROM Requests
```

You will get output as following.

```
Id    InvoiceRequestId  Index
2734  620               0
2735  620               1
2736  621               0
2737  622               0
2738  622               1
2739  622               2
```

To update back you can use following query

```
UPDATE R
SET R.[Index] = N.[Index]

FROM Requests R
INNER JOIN
(

SELECT Id, InvoiceRequestId,(ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(PARTITION BY  InvoiceRequestId 
    ORDER BY Id, InvoiceRequestId ASC)-1) AS [Index]
 FROM Requests
 ) N
 ON N.Id = R.ID AND N.InvoiceRequestId= R.InvoiceRequestId
```