# Change mysql auto increment id column value

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have a mysql table with an `gpid AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE` column.

After filling this table (which has 50M+ entries), I have realized that mysql still increments `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns if transaction fails because of an IntegrityError, and understandably so.

The results are gaps in `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns, with `gpid` jumping values (for exemple from `gpid == 3` to `gpid == 5` between two consecutive rows). While this is not an issue for machines, it is one for my coworkers and I. The purpose of this column was, among other things, to represent the exact number of rows in the table.

Is there a way to change all `gpid` column values to a nice range (from 1 to 53926669), respecting the order the rows were inserted in the table, without having to drop/refill the table? Refilling would take me a long time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL, just like other databases, does not guarantee the absence of gaps in auto-increment column. Renumbering the table may fix the issue at a particular point in time, but gaps may (and most likely) will appear in the future.

If you want a monotically increasing sequence, then auto-increment is not what you need. Instead, you can for example create a view, and use `row_number()`:

```
create view myview as
select t.*, row_number() over(order by gpid) as new_gpid
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GMB, this will do the trick. However from what I have just read about views, I cannot find out how to replace values inside the `gp` table using the view. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: I have answered my question with this topic [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number/21544096]