# Update with nested select in from statement does not work mysql

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, window-functions

Here is an error I don't understand:

```
     mysql> UPDATE gp
    -> SET gp.gpid = gp.new_gpid
    -> FROM (
    ->       SELECT gpid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [gpid]) AS new_gpid
    ->       FROM gp
    ->       ) gp;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (
      SELECT gpid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [gpid]) AS new_gpid
      ' at line 3
```

As far as I can tell nested `SELECT` in a `FROM` statement seems to be depreciated.

Am using mysql 8.0.21

Any help to make this query work would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

EDIT 1:
What I am trying to achieve is to update the gpid column with row numbers instead of the actual `AUTO_INCREMENT` id, which contains gaps in between ids, the explanation in this post [Change mysql auto increment id column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930233/change-mysql-auto-increment-id-column-value/64930309#64930309)

Comment: Please include the rest of the update statement and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UPDATE... FROM ...` syntax is not supported by MySql.
You can do it with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE gp 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT gpid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY gpid) AS new_gpid
  FROM gp
) t ON t.gpid = gp.gpid
SET gp.gpid = t.new_gpid;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc274c15317ec9536078096d1a4af01e).

Answer (score 0):

Your nested query is selecting from 'gp' but is then aliased as 'gp' it can't select from itself.