# Update column enumerating row number in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck at a query in MySQL 5.7.
Simplified, i have a temporary table like this:

```
guid  B   C
 2   aa  55
 5   ab  66
 7   ac  77
 9   ad  88
```

What i want to do is, turn the column guid into an enumeration starting from 1, while not touching any data in the other columns:

```
guid  B   C
 1   aa  55
 2   ab  66
 3   ac  77
 4   ad  88
```

I have been looking for solutions involving ROW_NUMBER and ROW_ID but my syntax won't be accepted:

```
UPDATE temp_table
SET temp_table.guid = temp_table.New_guid
FROM (
      SELECT guid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [guid]) AS New_guid
      FROM temp_table
      ) x
```

I tried to adopt the above from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number), but it keeps sayng "FROM is not a valid input at this position".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use variables:

```
set @rn = 0;

update temp_table
    set guid = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by guid;
```

If you don't actually care about the current ordering you can use:

```
update temp_table tt cross join
       (select @rn := 0) params
    set tt.guid = (@rn := @rn + 1);
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use `order by` when the `update` has a `join`.