# Updating fields in sql incrementing by 1 each time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to construct an SQL query that would take a set of rows and renumber a field on all rows, starting at where they all match a session ID.

e.g.
before change:

```
SessionID  |  LineNumber  |  LineContents
----------------------------------------------
74666      |  1           | example content
74666      |  2           | some other content
74666      |  3           | another line
74666      |  4           | final line
```

after change (user has deleted line 2 so the 'LineNumber' values have updated to reflect the new numbering (i.e. line '3' has now become line '2' etc.):

```
SessionID  |  LineNumber  |  LineContents
----------------------------------------------
74666      |  1           | example content
74666      |  2           | another line
74666      |  3           | final line
```

So reflecting this in NON proper syntax would be something along these lines

```
i = 0;
UPDATE tbl_name
SET LineNumber = i++;
WHERE SessionID = 74666;
```

Searches a lot for this with no luck, any help is great :)

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What determines your order? Do you have an ID field, or date field?

Comment: I guess you mean i-- for each line with LineNumber greater than the deleted record LineNumber.

Comment: IS this your table or do you have any primaryKey or something like that ?

Comment: In reply to Gareth D - Yes there is a unique LineNumberID field I have left out
In reply to jpw - SQL server 2012
In reply to Suraj - yes there is a unique LineNumberID field I have left out

Comment: Was the SEQUENCE command even an option here?  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Row_Number()` function and `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT SessionID, LineNumber, LineContents,
         Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY SessionID ORDER BY LineNumber) Rn
  FROM Table1 
)
UPDATE CTE
SET LineNumber = Rn
WHERE SessionID = 74666;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c3466/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER ( MS SQL ) or ROWNUM ( Oracle ) or similar inside your UPDATE statement.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number)

[Or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390612/how-to-assign-row-number-to-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main ways to do that.

The first "low level" way is this one ([SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed162/3)):

```
DELETE FROM TestTable 
WHERE SESSIONID = 74666 AND LineNumber = 3;

UPDATE TestTable SET LineNumber = LineNumber-1
WHERE SESSIONID = 74666 AND LineNumber > 3

select * from TestTable -- check the result
```

Here we're assuming you know both LineNumber and SessionID.

The other way is through [t-SQL Triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), a little more complex but it helps you if you don't know info about the rows you're deleting. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE  TABLE Trial (
--   ID INT,
 SessionID INT , 
 LineNumber INT ,
 LineContent NVARCHAR(100)

)

INSERT  INTO dbo.trial
VALUES  ( 74666, 1, 'example content' ) ,
        ( 74666, 2, 'some other content' ),
        ( 74666, 4, 'another line' ),
        ( 74666, 5, 'final line' )
```

You can last deleted LineNumber value and can use that id in your update statement to update rest of the LineNumbers , for instance here Linenumber 3 is deleted so ,

```
   UPDATE dbo.trial SET LineNumber = LineNumber -1 WHERE LineNumber > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be really inclined to handle this differently if at all possible, and have the Linenumber generated on the fly, to avoid having to maintain a column, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T 
(   
    LineNumberID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    SessionID INT NOT NULL,
    LineContents NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT dbo.T (SessionID, LineContents)
VALUES 
    (74666, 'example content'),
    (74666, 'some other content'),
    (74666, 'another line'),
    (74666, 'final line');
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.V
AS
    SELECT  LinenumberID,
            SessionID,
            Linenumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SessionID ORDER BY LinenumberID),
            LineContents
    FROM    dbo.T;
GO
```

In this your View gives you what you need, and if I delete as follows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.V;

DELETE  dbo.V
WHERE   SessionID = 74666
AND     Linenumber = 3;

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.V;
```

You get the output:

```
LINENUMBERID    SESSIONID   LINENUMBER  LINECONTENTS
1               74666       1           example content
2               74666       2           some other content
3               74666       3           another line
4               74666       4           final line


LINENUMBERID    SESSIONID   LINENUMBER  LINECONTENTS
1               74666       1           example content
2               74666       2           some other content
4               74666       3           final line
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5eb04/1)**

So you maintain your sequential linenumber field without actually having to update a field. This of course only works if you can rely on a field (such as `CreatedDate`, or an ID column) to order by. Otherwise you will have to maintain it using triggers, and update statements as suggested in other answers.