# How to get data sequentially?

Tags: database, relational-database

This is an interview question.

This is a actual table `Employee`:

```
id  |  name  | salary
1   |    A   | 7000
2   |    B   | 6000
3   |    C   | 5000
4   |    D   | 5500
5   |    E   | 4000
6   |    F   | 4800
7   |    G   | 3000
8   |    H   | 2000
```

And I want a result like this:

```
id  |  name  | salary
1   |    C   | 5000
2   |    D   | 5500
3   |    E   | 4000
4   |    F   | 4800
5   |    G   | 3000
```

I want to show records whose salary between 5000 to 3000 but 1st column should be sequential.

When I perform query it shows this result.

```
id  |  name  | salary
3   |    C   | 5000
4   |    D   | 5500
5   |    E   | 4000
6   |    F   | 4800
7   |    G   | 3000
```

[here] what can I write then it will give proper result?

```
 select name, salary, [HERE]
 from Employee
 where salary between 5000 and 3000;
```

Comment: Is it mysql or another database? Or generic?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293390/sql-to-output-line-number-in-results-of-a-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard ANSI SQL <sup>(supported by all modern DBMS)</sup>

```
select row_number() over () as id
       name,
       salary
where salary between 5000 and 3000
```

Note that the order of rows (and in this case the "generated") id is undefined if you do not specify an `order by` clause. To get a "stable sort order", you should use something like this:

```
select row_number() over (order by salary) as id
       name,
       salary
where salary between 5000 and 3000
order by salary
```

Comment: SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeField) AS Row, *
FROM SomeTable;  its not working in lampp;

Comment: @user2963592: MySQL isnt' advanced enough. They have not kept up with modern SQL features (although that standard is already 10 years old). If you want a DBMS specific solution, you should tag your question accordingly. At least mention it in the question

Comment: Then what can I do for MySQL. is there any option.?

Comment: @user2963592: I don't think so (apart from Sashi's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

For **MYSQL** ::

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_number, 
       t.*
FROM ( 
select name, salary from Employee
 where salary between 5000 and 3000) t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Comment: good its working but when user want only one column then it fail. its depend on next column which is specify in SELECT clause.

Comment: @AjinkyaKasar: didn't get you?

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, for MS SQL server the solution can be found in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293399/2822268

Comment: Link only answers are usually frowned upon. If you really think it's the same question, you should vote to close this as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for this tipp. Unfortunately I am currently not able to vote for closing as a duplicate as I am very new on this platform. I thought the solution for the other question could help here - the question itself is not exactly a duplicate.